# Why do I get an error when using `pivot_wider()` from the `tidyverse` package?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a dataframe with a numerical variable (`Acc`) and four categorical variables (`ID`,`Datetime`, `Period` and `State`).

```
# My data
df <- data.frame(ID=c(rep(c("A"),8),rep(c("B"),8)),
                 Datetime=c("2020-08-05 12:00:00","2020-08-05 17:00:00","2020-08-05 18:03:00","2020-08-05 22:54:00","2020-08-06 01:08:00","2020-08-06 13:26:00","2020-08-06 19:04:00","2020-08-08 11:00:00",
                            "2020-08-04 03:00:00","2020-08-04 15:00:00","2020-08-04 23:00:00","2020-08-06 14:00:00","2020-08-06 17:00:00","2020-08-06 20:00:00","2020-08-07 04:00:00","2020-08-07 16:00:00"),
                 Period=c("Day","Day","Day","Night","Night","Day","Night","Day","Night","Day","Night","Day","Day","Night","Night","Day"),
                 State=c(1,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1),
                 Acc=c(1.1,2.3,1.7,1.4,0.1,1.9,2.9,2.3,1.1,0.1,1.4,0.2,2.6,1.3,1.7,1.0))

df$Datetime <- as.POSIXct(df$Datetime,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="UTC")

df

   ID            Datetime Period State Acc
1   A 2020-08-05 12:00:00    Day     1 1.1
2   A 2020-08-05 17:00:00    Day     2 2.3
3   A 2020-08-05 18:03:00    Day     1 1.7
4   A 2020-08-05 22:54:00  Night     1 1.4
5   A 2020-08-06 01:08:00  Night     1 0.1
6   A 2020-08-06 13:26:00    Day     1 1.9
7   A 2020-08-06 19:04:00  Night     2 2.9
8   A 2020-08-08 11:00:00    Day     2 2.3
9   B 2020-08-04 03:00:00  Night     1 1.1
10  B 2020-08-04 15:00:00    Day     1 0.1
11  B 2020-08-04 23:00:00  Night     1 1.4
12  B 2020-08-06 14:00:00    Day     2 0.2
13  B 2020-08-06 17:00:00    Day     2 2.6
14  B 2020-08-06 20:00:00  Night     1 1.3
15  B 2020-08-07 04:00:00  Night     1 1.7
16  B 2020-08-07 16:00:00    Day     1 1.0
```

I am trying to estimate mean `Acc` per `ID`, `Day`, `Period` and `State`. To do so, I am trying to apply this code:

```
library(tidyverse)

  df %>% 
    group_by(ID, Day = as.factor(as.Date(Datetime)), Period, State, .drop = FALSE) %>% 
    summarise(Acc = mean(Acc, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = c(State, Period),
                values_from = Acc,
                names_prefix = "State.") %>% 
    select(!State.NA_NA)
```

I should get this:

```
#> `summarise()` regrouping output by 'ID', 'Day', 'Period' (override with `.groups` argument)
#> # A tibble: 10 x 6
#> # Groups:   ID, Day [10]
#>    ID    Day        State.1_Day State.2_Day State.1_Night State.2_Night
#>    <chr> <fct>            <dbl>       <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>
#>  1 A     2020-08-04        NA          NA           NA             NA  
#>  2 A     2020-08-05         1.4         2.3          1.4           NA  
#>  3 A     2020-08-06         1.9        NA            0.1            2.9
#>  4 A     2020-08-07        NA          NA           NA             NA  
#>  5 A     2020-08-08        NA           2.3         NA             NA  
#>  6 B     2020-08-04         0.1        NA            1.25          NA  
#>  7 B     2020-08-05        NA          NA           NA             NA  
#>  8 B     2020-08-06        NA           1.4          1.3           NA  
#>  9 B     2020-08-07         1          NA            1.7           NA  
#> 10 B     2020-08-08        NA          NA           NA             NA
```

However, I get the message `Error in map_lgl(.x, .p, ...) : object 'State' not found`.

I don't understand where is the mistake. I guess it is something silly, but I have been hours thinking on that and nothing.

Does someone shed light on why I get an error message?

Comment: I get the same output as shown. Are you sure there are no other lines in your script/code that you are running?

Comment: Or other packages interferring with tidyverse functions? E.g. did you try specifically calling tidyverse functions with e.g. `tidyverse::select` or `tidyverse::group_by`?

Comment: Thanks for your time guys. Before doing that I called other multiple packages. However, I added `tidyverse::` before any of the functions, and I always got the same message: `Error: 'group_by' is not an exported object from 'namespace:tidyverse'`. This same message for the other functions...

Answer (score 3):

Does this work:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(ID, Day = as.factor(as.Date(Datetime)), Period, State, .drop = FALSE) %>% 
  summarise(Acc = mean(Acc, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% na.omit() %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = c(State, Period),
              values_from = Acc,
              names_prefix = "State.") %>%  complete(ID, nesting(Day)) %>% arrange(ID, Day) %>% distinct()
`summarise()` regrouping output by 'ID', 'Day', 'Period' (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 10 x 6
# Groups:   ID, Day [10]
   ID    Day        State.1_Day State.2_Day State.1_Night State.2_Night
   <fct> <fct>            <dbl>       <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>
 1 A     2020-08-04        NA          NA           NA             NA  
 2 A     2020-08-05         1.4         2.3          1.4           NA  
 3 A     2020-08-06         1.9        NA            0.1            2.9
 4 A     2020-08-07        NA          NA           NA             NA  
 5 A     2020-08-08        NA           2.3         NA             NA  
 6 B     2020-08-04         0.1        NA            1.25          NA  
 7 B     2020-08-05        NA          NA           NA             NA  
 8 B     2020-08-06        NA           1.4          1.3           NA  
 9 B     2020-08-07         1          NA            1.7           NA  
10 B     2020-08-08        NA          NA           NA             NA  
>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where in your code the error was coming from but I think it was from the final `select` line. Instead of selecting anything that wasn't State.NA_NA I switched it to keep everything column that didn't contain an NA in it. This seems to get the desired output.

Also looking at the comments I would recommend calling each tidyverse package with the syntax `dplyr::select` as you may be unintentionally calling a different `select`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(ID=c(rep(c("A"),8),rep(c("B"),8)),
                 Datetime=c("2020-08-05 12:00:00","2020-08-05 17:00:00","2020-08-05 18:03:00","2020-08-05 22:54:00","2020-08-06 01:08:00","2020-08-06 13:26:00","2020-08-06 19:04:00","2020-08-08 11:00:00",
                            "2020-08-04 03:00:00","2020-08-04 15:00:00","2020-08-04 23:00:00","2020-08-06 14:00:00","2020-08-06 17:00:00","2020-08-06 20:00:00","2020-08-07 04:00:00","2020-08-07 16:00:00"),
                 Period=c("Day","Day","Day","Night","Night","Day","Night","Day","Night","Day","Night","Day","Day","Night","Night","Day"),
                 State=c(1,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1),
                 Acc=c(1.1,2.3,1.7,1.4,0.1,1.9,2.9,2.3,1.1,0.1,1.4,0.2,2.6,1.3,1.7,1.0))

df$Datetime <- as.POSIXct(df$Datetime,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="UTC")

df
#>    ID            Datetime Period State Acc
#> 1   A 2020-08-05 12:00:00    Day     1 1.1
#> 2   A 2020-08-05 17:00:00    Day     2 2.3
#> 3   A 2020-08-05 18:03:00    Day     1 1.7
#> 4   A 2020-08-05 22:54:00  Night     1 1.4
#> 5   A 2020-08-06 01:08:00  Night     1 0.1
#> 6   A 2020-08-06 13:26:00    Day     1 1.9
#> 7   A 2020-08-06 19:04:00  Night     2 2.9
#> 8   A 2020-08-08 11:00:00    Day     2 2.3
#> 9   B 2020-08-04 03:00:00  Night     1 1.1
#> 10  B 2020-08-04 15:00:00    Day     1 0.1
#> 11  B 2020-08-04 23:00:00  Night     1 1.4
#> 12  B 2020-08-06 14:00:00    Day     2 0.2
#> 13  B 2020-08-06 17:00:00    Day     2 2.6
#> 14  B 2020-08-06 20:00:00  Night     1 1.3
#> 15  B 2020-08-07 04:00:00  Night     1 1.7
#> 16  B 2020-08-07 16:00:00    Day     1 1.0

df %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(ID, Day = as.factor(as.Date(Datetime)), Period, State, .drop = FALSE) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(Acc = mean(Acc, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = c(State, Period),
              values_from = Acc,
              names_prefix = "State.") %>% 
  dplyr::select(!contains("NA"))
#> `summarise()` regrouping output by 'ID', 'Day', 'Period' (override with `.groups` argument)
#> # A tibble: 10 x 6
#> # Groups:   ID, Day [10]
#>    ID    Day        State.1_Day State.2_Day State.1_Night State.2_Night
#>    <fct> <fct>            <dbl>       <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>
#>  1 A     2020-08-04        NA          NA           NA             NA  
#>  2 A     2020-08-05         1.4         2.3          1.4           NA  
#>  3 A     2020-08-06         1.9        NA            0.1            2.9
#>  4 A     2020-08-07        NA          NA           NA             NA  
#>  5 A     2020-08-08        NA           2.3         NA             NA  
#>  6 B     2020-08-04         0.1        NA            1.25          NA  
#>  7 B     2020-08-05        NA          NA           NA             NA  
#>  8 B     2020-08-06        NA           1.4          1.3           NA  
#>  9 B     2020-08-07         1          NA            1.7           NA  
#> 10 B     2020-08-08        NA          NA           NA             NA
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks @Jeffrey Brabec, unfortunatlly, your code does not work neither. I get the message `Error: `!contains("NA")` must evaluate to column positions or names, not a logical vector`. I am going to both update `tidyverse` and open a new version calling only to `tidyverse`... Maybe I can solve it with that... It has to be related with that, because I am coping and pasting your code in my Rstudio and running it.

Comment: That may be the issue. I’m using the latest tidyverse packages so there may have been some syntactic changes made that your versions don’t recognize. I’d also recommend stepping through each line and seeing which one is throwing the error. Might help you narrow in on the problem

Comment: The problem is the last line (`select()`). I don't know why, but I get an error message independently of if I use `!contains("NA")` or `!State.NA_Day`. I have realized that this is only for removing the columns which contain `NA` in the columns name. In the worst case, I remove them selecting the other columns in the normal way (`df <- df[,c()]`). However, I wonder what is happening. I have installed again `tidyverse` (vs. 1.3.0 now) and I have opened a new project in which I only read `tidyverse`, so I don't know what else it can be...

Comment: Hmm i'm not sure what the problem could be. Having run through @Karthik S's answer below, as long as none of those functions drop errors, it should work the way that you need it to without having to rely on `select` or using indexing.

Comment: I am updating all the packages that I had in Rstudio without updating. It is taking a while. I hope that the problem could be related to some of those packages (they are tens). I think that `tidyverse` is composed by other packages, right? I don't know if some of those updates could change things... Let see... The last version of `tidyverse` is `1.3.0`? right? Thanks for your time @Jeffrey Brabec.

Comment: Yes 1.3.0 is the latest! And you’re welcome. Sorry I couldn’t be more help!

Comment: Just to let you know! It works now!! Both your proposal as well as @Karthik S's one. I updated all the packages, so I guess that the problem was with some package. Thanks for your time and help Jeffrey.